# how to mock in GWT Tests

Tags: gwt, mocking, gwtp

I'm developping an application using GWT and the framework [GWTP](http://code.google.com/p/gwt-platform/) to use MVP patterns. For almost each view, I write a test inheriting GWTTestCase.

And almost each time, I do the same mistake: I call Mockito to mock some stuff (like the ResourceBundle interfaces) and get my test failing because mockito can't be converted by GWT compiler.

Is there any specific mock framework that I could use in this case?

Answer (score 1):

using MVP allows you to create tests in JRE. the idea of MVP is to minimizing the dependency on GWT Test case. you should test only the presenter because the presenter should contain all the logic and the view must be used only for decorations i.e creating panels, buttons design and so on. the views should be DUMP. if you haven't take a look at these two article i advice you to do so . [MVP1](https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/articles/mvp-architecture) and [MVP2](https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/articles/mvp-architecture-2) and here is a [link](https://github.com/webmaster1803/ExReport) to a simple app,i am developing now, for expenses managing you can take a look at my test in the client side. i am using mockito btw. good luck and i expect feedback from you.

Comment: I agree with you and putting most of the logic in the presenter is always what I try to do. However, I still need some GWTTestCase , for instance when I have some code playing with JSON with the library com.google.gwt.json.client.